# Redirect back functionality in watchOs app

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, auth0

I want to use login with Auth0 in my watchOs app.
I have successfully implemented the "Sign in with apple" and after that used Auth0 for same.

Now I also want to implement the other way of auth0 login like sign in with Facebook, twitter etc. and as per auth0 guideline it will be possible by opening it in browser and redirect back to app . but apple do not provide the functionality to open browser and redirect back to app. I have followed below link

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ios-swift-siwa/00-login

is there any other way to implement auth0 for watchOs app or let me know if I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

I work with the Auth0 Community and I wanted to reach out and let you know that we don't have anything for that particularly at this time. However you should make the suggestion with your use case to our product team at [Auth0.com/feedback](https://auth0.com/feedback). Each request is reviewed by our product team and helps shape the future going forward. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I have submitted same query in above mentioned link. Hope your team will response soon else have to go with some other approach like API approach or Universal login .